# create a Calibration Board

Tags: image-processing, matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, camera-calibration

How could I know the best size of the board for my camera?
My camera is Canon D-100 It's 18 megapix
I have created a board consist of 14*10 squares 
the length of each square is 7*7cm
I need to know what the step of choosing the number of squares ?
and How could I know the best dimension for each square ?
Thank you very much

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What sort of calibration?

Answer (score 1):

You should position the board at roughly the same distance from the camera as the distance between the camera and your objects of interest. The board should be big enough to cover a good portion of the field of view at that distance.

Another point: ideally, your board should have an even number of squares along one side, and an odd number of squares along the other.  Then the orientation of the board can be detected unambiguously.

Finally, since you have a "matlab" tag on your question, please check out the [Camera Calibrator app](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/find-camera-parameters-with-the-camera-calibrator.html), which is a part of the latest release of the Computer Vision System Toolbox for MATLAB.